# How to debug my Grails application in IntelliJ?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, debug-mode

I am using this specific command to run my Grails application `clean bootRun -Dgrails.env=test`.

I would like run my application (with the same configuration) in debug mode from IntelliJ.

What Run/Debug configurations should be used to run the app in debug mode with the same options as in the command above?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [debugging a Grails app from IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31274095/debugging-a-grails-app-from-intellij)

Comment: I want to know how to run this command `gradlew clean bootRun -Dgrails.env=test` in debug mode